# zfs change device path

Tags: linux, usb, zfs

i have 2 zfs-fuse pools running on three external usb drives, since they are usb drives they will have different names when they are pluged in.

zfs status -x
is listing the pools and the devices as unavailable and as corrupted, which is obvious as one of the listed devices is now the systems *swap* space.

How do I change the device paths of each zfs pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: Before disconnecting or shutting down, you should export “external” pools. When you import them again, the current set of device names will be used.

If you want to import a pool using “predictable device names”, you can use the method outlined in [Arch Linux’ ZFS Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_ZFS#Configure_the_root_filesystem):

```
zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id <poolname>
```

The important part is the `-d` parameter. It tells `zpool` where to look for devices. The `/dev/disk/by-id` directory should always be available when using a reasonably recent distribution with udev.

That being said, I didn’t have that much luck with this method, the device names always reverted to their “sda1” state after rebooting.